# What is the replacement for Set-WindowsAzureLog?

Tags: powershell, azure, performancecounter

I am looking at installing performance counters on Azure azure web roles.

I would like this to be done in powershell rather than directly in the web role as it belongs to the Infrastructure team, not development and they need to be free to add/remove counters as they see fit. I have no custom counters at this time.

All references/articles I have seen are either hard coded or rely on `Set-WindowsAzureLog` which seems to be deprecated.

I am using the powershell cmdlets from https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/downloads/ , which seems to have no obvious equivalent.

**UPDATE:** I found the code http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/releases/view/84058, which is a download not in the source browser as I initially expected. It seems to write to the logs but I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

As for the replacement cmdlet to `Set-WindowsAzureLog` I don't think there is one currently.

Since you are in PowerShell you can use .NET classes to achieve what you want to do.
Here is an MSDN article on logging configuration.

[How to Remotely Change the Diagnostic Monitor Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432992.aspx)

If you include the Azure SDK assembly with your scripts and load it into PowerShell you should be able to accomplish your goal.

Hope that helps.